# Why v-if is not showing the heading when boolean value changes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am very new to vue js. I am just learning to use it from laracasts. What I want to do is communicate between root class and subclass. Here, user will put a coupon code and when he changes focus it will show a text.

My html code is like this

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <coupon @applied="couponApplied">
        <h1 v-if="isCouponApplied">You have applied the coupon.</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
```

My main.js is like this,

```
Vue.component('coupon', {
    template: '<input @blur="applied">',
    methods: {
        applied()
        {
            this.$emit('applied');  
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        isCouponApplied:false,
    },
    methods:{
        couponApplied()
        {
            this.isCouponApplied = true;
        }
    }
});
```

I am checking using vue devtools extension in chrome. There is no error. The blur event is triggered. `isCouponApplied` also  changes to true. But the h1 is not showing. Can anyone show me where I made the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not closing your `<coupon>` tag

```
<div id="root">
    <coupon @applied="couponApplied"></coupon>
    <h1 v-if="isCouponApplied">You have applied the coupon.</h1>
</div>
```

Should fix your issue. If you don't close your tag, the parser will auto-close it, but it will do so at the close of its wrapping container (the root div), so the `h1` content will be seen as inside the `<coupon>` element, and will be replaced by your component's template.

Comment: Adding up on the above, a self-closing tag may also work: `<coupon @applied="couponApplied"/ >`